# Cloud Functions "event=>" Documentation

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Cloud Functions and I think they are cool. I have searched for the documentation of complete list of methods that can be invoked by "event" and how to use them but I've not find any. Example in the code below event is used to invoke data.current.child etc. Can someone please help me find documentation of methods under "event".

```
 exports.getPath = functions.database.ref('/Transaction/{id}')
.onWrite(event => {
  // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
  const trans = event.data.current.child('Request').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the Cloud Function `Event` interface is [provided here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Event).

The data in the event depends on the event type.  There are classes for each:

- `AnalyticsEvent` for Analytics events
- `UserRecord` for Auth events.
- `DeltaSnapshot` for Realtime Database events.
- `Message` for Pub/Sub events.
- `ObjectMetadata` for Storage events